# c# wcf duplex communication

Tags: wcf, communication, duplex

I have to write an online chess program using WCF. I'm new to service programming, so could you please give me some advice.

I thought of using duplex communication, so that the service could poll the database and call the client, if the opponent has made a new step. but I don't think this would be a quite optimal solution. Could you please tell me what better alternatives can be here?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of clients that will use the service. If for example the clients are .NET clients you could use wcf Net.Tcp communication and set up a callback contract that the clients need to implement and the service can call when someone makes a move. If you use other type of clients polling is probably the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I knew there must be a better thing to do.